# Program not reading input correctly

Tags: java, input

I looked for a little on similar questions and couldn't find one that was answered well enough to help my situation.

I am trying to read user input and it seems like its not setting the variable to the input.

For example:

```
 System.out.println("Would you like Syrup?(Y/N)");
   String wantSyrup = keyboard.next();
   char syrupWant = wantSyrup.charAt(0);

   switch (syrupWant){

   case 'y':
       System.out.println("Which syrup would you like?");
        System.out.println("Hot fudge, Chocolate, Caramel, Strawberry");
         syrupChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered: "+syrupChoice);

        if((syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(hotFudge)) | (syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(chocolateSyrup))|
        (syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(caramel))| (syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(strawberrySyrup))){
        System.out.println(syrupChoice);
        }else{
        System.out.println("Not a valid choice. You now have Hot Fudge as your syrup.");
         syrupChoice = hotFudge;
         }
       break;
   default: break;
   }
```

Is it that extremely long If statement thats messing it up? I've never put that many ORs in one if.

The Console is coming back with this when i enter any type of syrup..

```
Would you like Syrup?(Y/N)
y
Which syrup would you like?
Hot fudge, Chocolate, Caramel, Strawberry
caramel
You entered: 
Not a valid choice. You now have Hot Fudge as your syrup.
```

Note: It does wait until i enter a value. Thats why i have

```
         syrupChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
    keyboard.nextLine();
```

But no matter what i enter it comes up blank. I obviously want it to read the input correctly and Print the correct values. (if invalid data, change to hot fudge.)

EDIT ** I Changed the code now to:

```
 System.out.println("Would you like Syrup?(Y/N)");
   String wantSyrup = keyboard.next();
   char syrupWant = wantSyrup.charAt(0);

   switch (syrupWant){

   case 'y':
       System.out.println("Which syrup would you like?");
        System.out.println("Hot fudge, Chocolate, Caramel, Strawberry");
         syrupChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered: "+syrupChoice);

      if(syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(hotFudge)
              || syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(chocolateSyrup)
              || syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(caramel)
              || syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(strawberrySyrup))
                {
                    System.out.println(syrupChoice);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Not a valid choice. You now have Hot Fudge as your syrup.");
                    syrupChoice = hotFudge;
                }
                break;
    default: break;
        }
```

**Still the same outcome**

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of small problems. First of all, `|` is a bitwise or operator, `||` is the logical or operator. Also you had some extraneous `keyboard.nextLine()`s.

```
System.out.println("Would you like Syrup?(Y/N)");
String wantSyrup = keyboard.nextLine();
char syrupWant = wantSyrup.charAt(0);

switch (syrupWant){
    case 'y':
        System.out.println("Which syrup would you like?");
        System.out.print("Hot fudge, Chocolate, Caramel, Strawberry: ");
        syrupChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("You entered: ");

        if(syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(hotFudge)
            || syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(chocolateSyrup)
            || syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(caramel)
            || syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(strawberrySyrup))
        {
            System.out.println(syrupChoice);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not a valid choice. You now have Hot Fudge as your syrup.");
            syrupChoice = hotFudge;
        }
        break;
    default: break;
}
```

Comment: I changed my code to this fashion, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the binary OR: `|` with a logical OR: `||` in your if statement:

`if((syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase
    (hotFudge)) ||     (syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase
    (chocolateSyrup)) ||      (syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase
    (caramel)) || (syrupChoice.equalsIgnoreCase
    (strawberrySyrup))){
        System.out.println(syrupChoice); }`